# A Possible Logical Problem with Showing that $x$ is a Boundary Point Whenever It is an Isolated Point

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Prove: If $x$ is an isolated point of a set $S$, then $x \in \mathrm{bd} \, S$.

I have two ways to solving this problem, but I believe the first one has a logical issue which I will explain below. Thanks for any help.

**Solution 1** Let $x$ be an isolated point of a set $S$, and let $N$ be an arbitrary neighborhood of $x$. Suppose that $N \subseteq S$. But if $x \notin S'$ where $S'$ is the set of accumulation points of $S$, then there exists a deleted neighborhood $N^*$ such that $N^* \cap S^c \neq \varnothing$, and since $x \not \in S^c$, the whole neighborhood $N_1 \cap S^c \neq \varnothing$. But this contradicts the fact that every $N \subseteq S$, so there are no neighborhoods that are contained in $S$. Because $x \in S$ and given the above information, we conclude that $x \in \mathrm{bd} \, S$.

But I think there is a problem with the above proof. I think that allowing $N$ to be arbitrary and setting $N \subseteq S$, deriving a contradiction, and then concluding that no such $N$ exists is fallacious, because all I have proven is that not every $N$ is a subset of $S$; there could still be some $N$ that is in fact a subset of $S$ and others not. I have seen another solution that begins the same way I did, but then says that every deleted neighborhood of $S$ will have a nonempty intersection with $N$, and then derives a contradiction. But I cannot help but think that this approach suffers from the same issue that I am raising with my first solution, namely, that we have shown that not every neighborhood is a subset of $S$. If I am wrong, what am I confusing?

So I attempted another solution.

**Solution 2** Suppose $x$ is an isolated point and suppose there exists a neighborhood $N$ that is contained in $S$. Since $x \not \in S'$, there exists a deleted neighborhood $N^*$ such that $N^* \subseteq S^c$. But then $N \cap N^* \neq \varnothing$ since either $N \subseteq N^*$ or $N^* \subseteq N$. Thus there are no neighborhoods contained in $S$, so $x \in \mathrm{bd} \, S$.

To be clear about my issue with the first solution, I am translating the statement, "There are no neighborhoods contained in $S$" to $\sim \exists \, N : \, p(N)$ where $p(N)$ means $N$ is contained in $S$.

Thanks.

Note: Just in case this proof doesn't hold for the general $R^n$, I am dealing with just the one dimensional case.